# How is location determined from internet?

Tags: language-agnostic, location, ip, ip-address, ethernet

I was just installing Ubuntu and noticed it was downloading updates from **ca**.archive.ubuntu.com. How did it know I was in Canada? As far as I'm aware an IP packet carries no information regarding physical (geographcial location) and there is no stipulation in the Ethernet standard saying anything about information regarding location.

So how do things such as geolocation work? For example [this website](http://remote.12dt.com/lookup.php) tells you which country your IP address belongs to. Is it just a matter of looking up an IP address in a table? If so where does the data come from, it's not as if people actively signup to have their IP address associated with the building address?

Comment: `Is it known that IP adress ranges belong to a certain ISP in a given area` Yes, basically. [From Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geolocation), "Geolocation usually works by automatically looking up an IP address on a WHOIS service and retrieving the registrant's physical address".

Comment: I voted to close this because geolocation is very easily searchable topic, and, as written, I don't believe this question is really fit for SO.

Comment: @admdrew how does WHOIS know the physical location?

Comment: @admdrew does the edit clear up the question?

Answer (score 3):

> > how does IP address geolocation work, does it just lookup the IP from a table?

Yes, that's exactly how it works.

IP geolocation is nothing more complicated than a database lookup. IP addresses are assigned by [IANA](https://www.iana.org/numbers) to regional governing entities who then assign (sell) them to ISPs, governments and corporations (IBM for example has a dedicated block of IP addresses for themselves because they got into the internet game very early on).

Based on this fact we can sort of figure out where an IP address is located. IANA themselves publish the block level allocations on their site: https://www.iana.org/assignments/ipv4-address-space/ipv4-address-space.xml which is rendered beautifully in this XKCD comic: http://xkcd.com/195/.

As for the more detailed info like which city that IP address comes from, to get that information requires more data gathering. Some ISPs may tell you their assignment schemes, most dont. So most databases like whatismyipaddress.com painfully build theirs up by surveys (simply asking people where they are or via smartphone apps tapping into GPS), looking up whois databases (which may or may not lie) and careful guessing.

Comment: Can DNS or reverse DNS be used to determine location or is the entirely different?

Comment: The "whois" lookup I mentioned is DNS so yes, you can use DNS records to do this but as I also mentioned DNS records sometimes lie (I've registered domain names that claim to belong to US companies/organizations/entities in the past but pointing to servers in Malaysia)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your IP carries a geolocation as well.  I'm not sure that's the best way to describe it, as it doesn't really carry the information (I don't think?). This link gives a pretty good idea of the kind of details they can get from your ISP though:

http://whatismyipaddress.com/geolocation-accuracy

Of course all of that revealing information can be partially negated by using a proxy.

Comment: No the ip packet doesn't carry some explicit information saying which city you're located in. That's sort of my question, how does IP address geolocation work, does it just lookup the IP from a table? If so, where did the table come from?

Comment: Dug around a bit more.  Basically a third party provides the information from a database they maintain.  Example of said third party: http://www.maxmind.com/en/home  They get their data via this method (found on whatsmyipaddress.com) "We employ user-entered location data from sites that ask web visitors to provide their geographic location"